# Training a model when using Naive Bayes

Tags: python, machine-learning, sentiment-analysis, naivebayes

I have a movie review dataset and I want to perform sentiment analysis on it.

I have implemented this using logistic regression. Following are the steps that I took in the process:

1. Removed stop words and punctuation from each row in the dataset.
2. Split the data into train, validation and test set.
3. Created a vocabulary of words from the training set.
4. Added every word in the vocabulary as a feature. If this word is in the current row, its TF-IDF value is set as the value of the feature, else 0 is set as the value.
5. Train the model. During training, sigmoid function is used for calculating the hypothesis and cross entropy loss is used for cost function. Then using gradient descent, the weights of the model were updated.
6. Tune hyperparameters using validation set
7. Evaluate model using test set

Now, I need to implement the same thing using Naive Bayes and I'm confused as to how to approach this problem. I assume the first 4 steps are going to be the same. But what is the training step when using Naive Bayes? What is the loss function and cost function in this case? And where do I use the Bayes' theorem to calculate the conditional probability? And how do I update the weights and biases?

I've searched a lot of resources on the web and I've mostly only found implementations using sklearn with model.fit and model.predict and I'm having a hard time figuring out the math behind this and how it could be implemented using vanilla python.

Comment: Might be a better question for [stats.se] or [datascience.se] as it relates to the underlying math and theory and you don't have a [mcve] to share. That being said, although you want to code it from scratch, the [sklearn docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/naive_bayes.html) are a great starting point for the underlying math, including equations, descriptions of the classification algorithms, and links to papers

Comment: Additionally, you can also go to the [page for each NP classifier type](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.GaussianNB.html#sklearn.naive_bayes.GaussianNB) and, in the upper right corner near the title, you can click the link to the [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/95d4f0841/sklearn/naive_bayes.py#L120) and see _exactly_ how they implemented it inside the `.fit` method (GaussianNB linked for example purposes)

Comment: @G.Anderson thanks for the reply. I'm new to Naive Bayes and I just need to know do I need to calculate weights and biases for classification with Naive Bayes or I just need to compare the two conditional probabilities of a sentence being positive or negative and choose whichever is highest as the predicted class?

Answer (score 0):

In the case of Logistic regression or SVM, the model is trying to predict the hyperplane which best fits the data. And so these models will determine the `weights and biases`.

1. `Naive Bayes` is moreover a probabilistic approach. It completely depends on [Bayes' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem).
2. There will be `NO` weights and biases in NB, there will only be `CLASS WISE` probability values for each of the features (i.e, `words` in case of text).
3. To avoid zero probabilities or to handle the case of unseen data (`words` in case of text), use Laplace Smoothing.
4. `α` is called the smoothening factor. And this will be hyperparameter in NB
5. Use `log` for numeric stability.

---

- Test example: `This movie is great`
- After removing the stopwords: `movie great`
- From the training data, we already know prob value for the words `movie` and `great` both for `+ve` & `-ve` class.  Refer `STEP 2`.
- Prob of `great` for `+ve` class would be greater than the prob of `great` for `-ve` class. And for the word `movie`, prob values could be almost the same. (This highly depends on your training data. Here I am just making an assumption)

> positive class prob = P(`movie`/+ve) * P(`great`/+ve)
>
> negative class prob = P(`movie`/-ve) * P(`great`/-ve)

- Compare the class prob values & return the one having high prob value.

P.S

> If the number of words in the sentence is large in numbers, then the class value would become very very small. Using `log` would solve this problem.
>
> If the word `great` wasn't there in the training set, the class prob value would be 0. So use `smoothening factor-α` (Laplace smoothing)

Refer [sk-learn naive bayes](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/naive_bayes.html) for more detailed info